# MAX3232 overheating and using a lot of current when solar panel not connected

Tags: max3232

I have a weather station using li-ion batteries and being charged with a solar panel. While adding [MAX3232](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/max3232.pdf) chip I notice that sometimes the MAX3232 would overheat and use a lot of current. In search of an issue I uploaded a simple blink sketch. Instead of [FS312F-G](https://www.ic-fortune.com/upload/Download/FS312F-G-DS-12_EN.pdf) I also use [DW01C-G](https://www.ic-fortune.com/upload/Download/DW01x-DS-17_EN_53783.pdf).

I then discovered that chip overheats only if I plug in the battery without the solar panel. If I first connect solar panel (that is exposed to the sun) then start the circuit and then later plugin the  battery it works without a problem. If I just plug in the battery without the solar panel this problem appears every single time.

I searched online and there seems to be quite some topic related to MAX3232 overheating but they don't seem to be related to my issue according to my knowlege. I'm not sure if there is problem how I merged the charging circuit with the MAX3232 or if it is just issue with the MAX3232 or some components around it. I'm thinking of using the MAX3221 in my next design since it has an auto shutdown function which would be useful in my case since I don't use serial on every board but I'm not sure if this would avoid the issue.

Here is the [easyeda link to the project](https://oshwlab.com/jaka87/new-vetercek)

[image: scheme]

Comment: The MAX3232 charge pump caps are 10x as large than recommended. There are no internal pull-up or pull-down resistors on TTL/CMOS inputs so one input is always floating and one input floats until MCU boots up and configures the pin as output. Floating inputs are bad. Have you checked that the MCU URX pin is never an output so the chips would both drive the node to different potentials? Oh and since battery voltage can be 2.7 to 4.2 the charge pump caps must be selected based on that. And the chip does not need to work below 3.0V so battery can be a problem.

Comment: Is the FW doing something different when the panel is connected and sees the charging current or something? The link doesn't open btw, is it a public design?

Comment: Have you measured supply voltages without and with battery? In both cases where battey is plugged in last and first?

Comment: Thx for pointing out the issues. I updated the link to the project. The software on the chip is currently just a blink program and it does absolutely nothing except turn on and of the LED. In the case where this issue happen the voltage is 3.7V and when i start the PCB with solar and then turn it off it is 3.8V (no issue)

Comment: @Justme i changed the caps to 0.1 uF and it seems to be working fine now. Thx for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a snap of your circuit: -

[image]

And here's what it says in the data sheet: -

[image]

I'm not saying that there are not other problems but, this one sticks out like a sore thumb.